# Unattended upgrade removed core packages

Tags: update

I'm using unattended upgrades on my RPi server which is running production grade personal servers (mail server, wordpress, nextcloud).
Last night, the unattended upgrade uninstalled a lot of package as if it was an "auto remove" :

```
Unattended upgrade result: Toutes les mises à niveau ont été 
 installées 

Package Upgrade Tentative: (<= translated from French)
 libegl-mesa0 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx 
 libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa libglx-mesa0 lxplug-volume 
 mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers raspi-config rc-gui rp-bookshelf 

Packages that were auto-removed:
 libqt5help5 qpdfview libxcb-icccm4 phantomjs smplayer 
 libqt5x11extras5 qpdfview-ps-plugin libqt5svg5 qt5ct smplayer-l10n 
 qjackctl libqt5designer5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5gui5 
 libqt5widgets5 qt5-style-plugins libpoppler-qt5-1 megasync 
 qpdfview-djvu-plugin smplayer-themes qpdfview-translations 
 libqt5webkit5 libqt5quick5 qt5-gtk-platformtheme python3-pyqt5 
 libegl1-mesa piclone uuid libwnck-3-common libwnck-3-0 
 epiphany-browser gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad libzbar0 libsbc1 bluealsa 
 gstreamer1.0-gl rtmpdump libsoundtouch1 libsrtp2-1 libgraphene-1.0-0 
 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libqt5sensors5 lxplug-network 
 gstreamer1.0-omx-rpi rp-prefapps zenity libyelp0 
 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 rc-gui yelp pipanel 
 gstreamer1.0-omx raspberrypi-ui-mods gstreamer1.0-omx-rpi-config 
 libdca0 libmplex2-2.1-0 lxplug-cputemp fio agnostics 
 gtk2-engines-pixflat libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 
 libqt5positioning5 gnome-themes-standard xserver-xorg-input-all 
 xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-libinput libinput10 
 xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-fbdev 
 xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo libpciaccess0 libnuma1 
 libxcb-render-util0 geoclue-2.0 lxplug-ptbatt libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 
 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0 lxplug-ejecter librdmacm1 epiphany-browser-data 
 libofa0 youtube-dl libgfapi0 libmpcdec6 libkate1 
 libgnome-desktop-3-12 zenity-common gtk2-engines-clearlookspix 
 libnice10 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 lxplug-volume libxcb-xkb1 
 libxcb-xinerama0 libspandsp2 libavahi-gobject0 libxcb-keysyms1 
 pixflat-icons python3-sip lxplug-magnifier iio-sensor-proxy libegl1 
 libegl-mesa0 mpv libmodplug1 libwildmidi2 libgfrpc0 libgfxdr0 
 libglusterfs0 rp-bookshelf libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libunwind8 
 fonts-piboto libqt5script5 libqt5webchannel5 libwacom-common 
 libwacom2 libinput-bin libmtdev1 rpd-plym-splash libqt5qml5 yelp-xsl 
 libva-wayland2 pi-greeter lxplug-bluetooth rpd-wallpaper libevdev2 
 xdg-dbus-proxy xserver-common libossp-uuid16 libvo-amrwbenc0 
 libvo-aacenc0 libwildmidi-config python3-pyxattr libmjpegutils-2.1-0 
 libxfont2 pishutdown libxcb-randr0 libwoff1 libvulkan1 

Packages that were kept from being auto-removed:
 libqt5help5
```

I checked the content of all the dpkg.log files I have to make sure I didn't remove a basic package by mistake but didn't find anything except ddclient mi July (and I'm sure I did some apt-get auto-remove since then).

A lot of things keep on working (and specifically all the server things which are running in a docker envt) but I lost my X server / lightdm / bluetooth and so on.

I reinstalled raspberrypi-ui-mods which brought back the desktop and a lot of the above uninstalled packages...

Any idea of what could have happened?